# How do I enable line numbers (on the left) every time I open Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I enable them by pressing: `M-x linum-mode`. How can I "translate" that into my.emacs file in order to enable it automatically every time I open EMACS?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Drop `(global-linum-mode t)` into your `.emacs` if you want it for every buffer. Otherwise, you can add a function to the appropriate hook of modes you're interested in to enable it for just that mode.

---

You should really read though the manual like I suggested in the last question of yours that I answered. ;)

Comment: Did you mean [all 800+ pages](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html) of it?

Comment: @AJ. And especially when it comes to Emacs, mostly because it's the best way to learn how to use the editor, but partly also because it's an increasingly rare and precious example of what really good documentation looks like.

Comment: If you're using Emacs 26.1 or later, use https://stackoverflow.com/a/50716229 instead (which is the fast new implementation of line-numbering).

Answer (score 14):

Since Emacs 26, the new way is to use (global-) display-line-numbers-mode:

```
(global-display-line-numbers-mode 1)
```

Answer (score 6):

One more solution is to use a `linum-mode`

`linum-mode` works fast on large files, so in order to enable it for your mode put this into your configuration:

```
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 
  (lambda ()
    (linum-mode 1)))
```

`linum-mode` is a part of Emacs after version 22
More documentation about this mode is [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers)

Answer (score 2):

You can also put `(line-number-mode 1)` into your `.emacs` file. This way you can also have it  be mode specific:

```
(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
  (line-number-mode 1))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
```

That way, it will only put the line numbers in if it's a C/C++ file.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider this code in your .emacs file:

```
;; always show line numbers
(global-linum-mode 1)
;; insert a space if running in text mode
(if window-system
    (progn)
  (setq linum-format "%d ")
  )
```

It adds a space between the line number and the editable lines in text mode, as it is done in graphics mode.